# Am trying to maven install the apache-storm repo i cloned. And am getting the following error on reaching storm-client. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project storm-client: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\FYP_1\storm\storm-client\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.

The following file AutoSSLTest in surefire-reports had this error:

---

### Test set: AutoSSLTest

`Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 s <<< FAILURE! - in AutoSSLTest testpopulateCredentials  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: failed to create base directory
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.AutoSSLTest.testpopulateCredentials(AutoSSLTest.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)`

Comment: does your user have the rights to create a directory?

Comment: Yes I have the access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tests were written without Windows in mind. This is one of them. Most of the Storm devs use Linux, and our CI also runs Linux. We've been improving the tests over the last while, but sometimes a Linux path slips through.

This is the line throwing the error https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/21bb1388414d373572779289edc785c7e5aa52aa/storm-client/test/jvm/org/apache/storm/security/auth/AutoSSLTest.java#L82

As you can see, it uses the "/tmp" directory, which doesn't exist on Windows. You can fix it by replacing the directory path with e.g. https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/db86bade005494aa26e782a3be5a64cb67ed522b/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/testing/TmpPath.java instead. So something like

```
try (TmpPath path = new TmpPath()) {
  baseDir = new File(path.getFile(), "autossl-test");
  ...
}
```

Feel free to submit an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira. If you want to raise a PR, you can do it at https://github.com/apache/storm/pulls

Comment: It still gives the same error.. Is using Linux the only way out??

Comment: No, you can add `-DskipTests` when building to skip tests. You can also install WSL and build Storm there (it's what I do). You can also raise an issue in JIRA and someone might take a look at it.